# Why is CAST function returning first value in comma-separated values, but not zero?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I executed following query to find the country name by the ID, I accidentally passed a string that contained comma-separated values.

```
   SELECT * FROM country WHERE id='6,AU,+61'
```

This query fetched that respective row.

When I tried casting this string into UNSIGNED using

```
  SELECT CAST('6,AU,+61' AS UNSIGNED)
```

It returned 6, the first value.

When I tried integer values separated by comma (for eg: `'7,8'`), it also returned 7. So, it wasn't taking any values after the first comma.

In case of `CAST('AU,+61' AS UNSIGNED)`, it returned zero.

Isn't `'7,8'` a string, so why is it not converting this into zero and taking first value instead?

Comment: What do you expect from the `CAST` conversion and why?

Comment: Well, it converts a string into 0, when casting it into UNSIGNED. So, why this different behavior for this comma-separated value?

Comment: it happens cause mysql  tries to parse provided string as number and that is  expected behaviour as normally if you want to turn a string into number it means you string contains number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql casts string to number by looking at the string from its left most char going right.

If the first char is a digit, it will iterate right until it reaches a non-digit char and will cast it to a number. if the string starts with a non-digit char it will cast to 0.

Thats why `CAST('AU,+61' AS UNSIGNED)` is `0`
While `CAST('7,8' AS UNSIGNED)` is `7`

However, The above is not documented specifically in the MySql Cast reference.
Although there are few examples over there and a specific line that implies such a behavior:

> there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

However this can be validated with few simple tests:

```
SELECT CAST('a7' as UNSIGNED) as 'col_a7'; -- 0
SELECT CAST('7q6' as UNSIGNED) as 'col_7q6'; -- 7
SELECT CAST('  7q6' as UNSIGNED) as 'col__7q6'; -- 7
SELECT CAST('1.4' as UNSIGNED) as 'col1.4'; -- 1
```

I might not be so clear in my description above, but these tests should clarify things.

Comment: Can you back up your answer with a reference?

Comment: Can you back your answer with a reference? E.g. a specification for the C++ [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function specifically says: _takes as many characters as possible to form a valid integer number representation and converts them to an integer value_. The MySQL's reference for the [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) does not say it

Comment: @cha, No there isn't such indeed. I tried to look myself for such and could not find. However as you'll see my updated answer I've made some tests to clarify it. Also i remember reading it somewhere but cannot find it now.

Comment: It seems that they used `atoi` as an underlying function for the CAST, however without a formal reference it is not recommended to rely on this behaviour in the production systems. It is clearly a "vendor specific thing", as it is different to SQL Server, Oracle or Postgres implementation

Comment: @cha I couldn't agree more. it's not recommended to use such code in production, and nothing guarantees it won't be changed in the future.